# Windows service lifetime and duty

Tags: c++, c, windows-services, daemon

I need a management application running with no-gui, doing some periodic jobs and connectable anytime by another console or desktop application.

On Linux, it would be a daemon. Is Windows service project equivalent on Windows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a program to run periodically, you should consider using Task Scheduler (the equivalent of cron) - setting this up will be much easier than using a Windows Service. However, if you need to be able to connect to it 24/7, you are correct that a Windows Service is equivalent.